# Sudden drop in page views?

Tags: google-analytics, traffic

My page views are suddenly dropped from 6000 to 2000 page views from yesterday.Is there any problem with server?please help me to fix.i have checked webmaster tools , everything is fine there.my site was appearing on 1st page on google search but from yesterday it has stopped in appearing in first page.THANK U

Comment: How would we know if something was wrong with your server? Remember, search results change constantly for many, many different reasons. Sometimes they help you, sometimes they hurt you, usually nothing changes. But unless you made a significant change or Google announces one on their end, there is no way to know why this happened.

Answer (score 1):

Increases or decreases in visitor volume to your site rarely has anything to do with your server directly.

If you aren't doing any kind of advertising or marketing to your site, then you have most likely been affected by a drop in organic rankings.

You say your site has stopped appearing on the 1st page of Google. Presumably this is for your brand keyword. I'm assuming this as you don't seem to know much about SEO (Search Engine Optimization) so I find it unlikely you're monitoring the keywords that are actually sending you that traffic.

If your brand keyword has dropped off the first page of Google, this could be due to a penalization of your site. This would also explain the large drop of traffic figures.

Keywords usually fluctuate a lot in their SERP positions. These fluctuations rarely cause huge drops in visitor volume to a site like they have in your case.

Your first step is to check Google Webmaster Tools to see if you have any messages about a penalty you have incurred. This should give you enough information to go and seek further advice once you know more about what precisely has happened. At the very least you should be able to rule out a site-wide penalty.

Comment: I have check webmaster tools...i didnt find any manual webspam actions...what should be further process to get my previous page views...there was sudden drop in pageviews...just a night before everything was fine.Next morning there sudden drop.

Answer (score 0):

Your page got a lower rank than other links, so that is why. You need to raise it by getting a reddit for your thing, a wikipedia, etc. Google looks at the alexa rank of your site to help it choose. It is best to raise this rank to go higher. Also, your site might have lost lots of links that linked to it. You need to grow them back.

Comment: how can that happen friend...it has now dropped to 1000 page views...my contents are daily updated,.??please help me to fix this..